# How to create migration which change one to one relation to one to many in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have tables `Clothes` and `Collections`. Original each `Clothes` could be only in one collection:

```cs
public class Clothes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CollectionId { get; set; }
    public int Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

However, now I need to change it, so each `Clothes` can be in several `Collections`. The changes in the logic are simple:

```cs
public class Clothes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClothesCollection> ClothesCollections { get; set; }
}

public class ClothesCollectionDbModel
{
    public int ClothesId { get; set; }
    public Clothes Clothes { get; set; }

    public int CollectionId { get; set; }
    public Collection Collection { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionDbModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClothesCollection> ClothesCollections { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is with data migration. I want to save all existing `CollectionId` for clothes and move them to a new table `ClothesCollection`.
I assume I need to do it in a new Migration with

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var data = migrationBuilder.Sql(@"SELECT ""Id"", ""CollectionId""FROM ""Clothes""");
}
```

But I don't see how I can load the SQL query result into memory and then use it to fill the new table.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting the question I realized that I don't need to load data into memory. The way I can solve the problem is to write the following code:

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO \"ClothesCollections\" (\"ClothesId\", \"CollectionId\") SELECT \"Id\", \"CollectionId\" FROM \"Clothes\"");
```

The thing is that I need to change the order of migration procedures here. By default, EF drops the existing column and indexes and then create a new table. I had to reorder them in the following way:

1. Create a `ClothesCollection` table, indexes, and foreign keys for it
2. Run the SQL script which copies data
3. Remove old index, foreign keys, column